# Get most recent status for each category

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I came across this interesting problem. I have a table named `email_track` to track email status for each category say (invitation, newsletter)

This is how my table data looks,
[image]

With these following queries I'm able to get most recent record for each `to_email`,

```
with `et2` as (
    select `et1`.`category`, `et1`.`to_email`, `et1`.`subject`, `et1`.`status`, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by `to_email` order by `id` desc) as `rn`
    from `email_track` `et1`
)
select * from `et2` where `rn` = 1;
```

[image]

```
select `et1`.`category`, `et1`.`to_email`, `et1`.`subject`, `et1`.`status`, `et2`.`id`
from `email_track` `et1`
left join `email_track` `et2` on (`et1`.`to_email` = `et2`.`to_email` and `et1`.`id` < `et2`.`id`)
where `et2`.`id` is null;
```

[image]

What I'm expecting is for email `john@example.com` I should get two records one for category invitation and the other for the newsletter. Now, we won't get that result since we partition by `to_email`
[image]

Comment: If you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I should get two records one for category invitation and the other for the newsletter. Now, we won't get that result since we partition by `to_email`.

Adding the `category` to the `partition by` clause of the window function should be enough to give your the result that you want:

```
with et2 as (
    select et1.category, et1.to_email, et1.subject, et1.status, 
        row_number() over(partition by to_email, category order by id desc) as rn
    from email_track et1
)
select * from et2 where rn = 1;
```